# Postgresql query to filter out based on jsonb child property

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm writing a long query on my rails application, part of it (last .where.not is that the inventory column's quantity property is not equal 0 on its entries) is not working. My current query looks like this:

```
@products = @products.offset(offset).limit(@limit)
.where(status: "visible")
.where("add_to_inventory =? OR (add_to_inventory =? AND inventory !=? )", false, true, '{}')
.where.not("ARRAY(select (jsonb_each(inventory)).value->>'quantity' as integer)='{0}'")
```

However, in my resultant products array, Product 14 manages to pass through this filtering, product 14 looks like so.

```
2.4.6 :001 > Product.find(14)
  Product Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."deleted" = $1 AND "products"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["deleted", "f"], ["id", 14]]
 => #<Product id: 14, deleted: false, category_id: 11, created_at: "2020-10-26 10:27:22", updated_at: "2020-11-10 16:26:11", final_price: 2342.0, status: 0, inventory: {"fsaf"=>{"sku"=>"", "barcode"=>"", "quantity"=>"0"}, "werwe"=>{"sku"=>"", "barcode"=>"", "quantity"=>"0"}}, add_to_inventory: true>
```

You can see that the inventory quantities are 0, how is this passing the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is passing the filter because there are two items in inventory. Current filter only filters out cases when

1. There are no items in inventory, or
2. There is one item in inventory with quantity of 0.

When there are two or more items in inventory, it's not going to filter it out.

If you need to filter out cases when *all* quantities are 0, you need to change the last line of the filter to

```rb
.where.not("ARRAY(select distinct (jsonb_each(inventory)).value->>'quantity' as integer)='{0}'")
```

Comment: Once again, thanks!, is there any resource you recommend for me to study such queries?

Comment: I usually use https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html plus stackoverflow search. And then a lot of experimenting in db console (`rails db` or `psql`) in order to get the query to a working state. It took me a lot of trial and error until I get the query right.